# Method returns int instead of char in java

Tags: java, methods, char

Like stated in the title I have a problem with a method in java that I wrote. This is the code:

```
public static char shift(char c, int k) {

    int x = c;

    int d = c - 65 + k;
    int e = c - 97 + k;

    if (x > 64 && x < 91 && d >= 0 ) {

        c = (char) ( d % 26 + 65);

    } else if (x > 96 && x < 123 && e >= 0 ) {

        c = (char) (e % 26 + 97 );
    }


    if (x > 64 && x < 91 && d < 0 ) {

        c = (char) ( (d + 26) % 26 + 65);

    } else if (x > 96 && x < 123 && e < 0 ) {

        c = (char) ( (e + 26) % 26 + 97);
    }

    return c;
}
```

I want to shift a letter in Alphabet. The code works perfectly if I use it like this (Caesar Chiper):

```
String s = " ";
    String text = readString();
    int k = read();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

        char a = text.charAt(i);
        int c = a;

        int d = a - 65 + k;
        int e = a - 97 + k;

        if (c > 64 && c < 91 && d >= 0 ) {

            a = (char) ( d % 26 + 65);

        } else if (c > 96 && c < 123 && e >= 0 ) {

            a = (char) (e % 26 + 97 );
        }
          if (c > 64 && c < 91 && d < 0 ) {

            a = (char) ( (d + 26) % 26 + 65);

        } else if (c > 96 && c < 123 && e < 0 ) {

            a = (char) ((e + 26) % 26 + 97);
        }

        s += a;
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I don't understand why the method shift returns an integer when I use it like this: shift('c', 5); it returns 104, which is the dec number for h. I'm a beginner in java and a slow person.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: a char is an int tooo

Comment: How did you use the returned value of shift()?

Comment: I know, but I want the method to return a character. If I write: char a = shift('c', 5);
        System.out.println(a); It shows me 104 and not 'h'.

Comment: I don't believe that. Since `a` is a `char`, `System.out.println(a);` will just print the character, and not a number. Doesn't matter where the value of the `char` comes from (a method, or by direct assignment).

Comment: With the `shift(char, int)` method above and testing it with `System.out.println('c', 5);` i get the output `h`, so there's something wrong with the way you're printing it.

Comment: I used a method write(); given to us by our teacher. I thought it does the same thing like System.out.println(); [we were told so]. Thanks a lot, and sorry for the stupid question >.<

Comment: Do you know that you can use e.g. `c > '@'` instead of `c > 64` (because `char` can be widened to `int`)? It just makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you're probably adding the unicodes of two characters.
This can happen if you do something like this:

```
System.out.println('b' + 'a');
```

or in your case

```
System.out.println(shift('c', 5) + 'a');
```

---

To get the desired result, convert the char to a string before printing:

```
String result = Character.toString(shift('c', 5));
System.out.println(result + 'a');
```

or

```
System.out.println(shift('c', 5) + "a");
```